# I keep getting a "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" error, and have no idea how to fix it

Tags: html, css, express

This is the error Im faced with. I have a localhost server stood up, and am trying to get my background, and logo working, but I am confused on file pathing. (/, ../, etc). Does anyone have an absolute solution to what Im doing wrong? Below Ive listed the html, css, and error message Im getting. If anyone can give me some helpful tips of EXACTLY what should be where using an example I would appreciate it. Thanks

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: If anyone has any tips Id gladly appreciate it! Ive been knocking my head aroun trying to solve it, and cant figure out if my path is wrong, or something else :l..

Comment: Remove"public" from src. You have defined incorrect path.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the paths of your code as follow:

**index.html**

```
<img src="Nozamalogo.png" width="112" height="28">
```

**style.css**

```
body, html, .navbar{
   background-image: url(../books.jpg);
}
```